# Bottom container inside stack moves upwards as keyboard opens on textfeild click - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, containers

I have a `stack` with list of content and custom dialogBox that I created. It contains `textfeild`. When I click the `textfeild`, keyboard opens and push dialog box way above the keyboard. There is alot of gap between the bottom of the dialog and the start of the keyboard. How can I keep the bottom of dialog stuck to the top the keyboard in a clean manner.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CombinedHomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  // --- Services Headings
  @override
  _CombinedHomeViewState createState() => _CombinedHomeViewState();
}

class _CombinedHomeViewState extends State<CombinedHomeView> {
  _showGrocOrderReviewDialog(Size _deviceSize) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: _deviceSize.height * 0.28,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "How was your last order?",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: fontMontserrat,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(_deviceSize.height * 0.02),
                  ),
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Add additional remarks',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: _deviceSize.height * 0.015,
                        fontFamily: fontMontserrat,
                        color: Colors.black38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SmallBtn(
                    passedText: "Cancel",
                    passedBorderColor: Colors.green,
                    passedBGColor: Colors.white,
                    passedFontColor: Colors.brown,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(child: SmallBtn(passedText: "Submit")),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        // ------------ List of content
        ListView( // few simple widgets here),
        // ------------ Dialog
        _showGrocOrderReviewDialog(_deviceSize)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Problem visual]

***You can ignore the below code. It is just a code of `SmallBtn` incase anyone needs it.***

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> // ignore: must_be_immutable
> class SmallBtn extends StatelessWidget {
>   final String passedText;
>   IconData passedIcon;
>   Color passedBGColor;
>   Color passedFontColor;
>   Color passedBorderColor;
>   bool isShadowEnabled;
>   SmallBtn({
>     @required this.passedText,
>     this.passedIcon,
>     this.passedBGColor,
>     this.passedFontColor,
>     this.passedBorderColor,
>     this.isShadowEnabled,
>   });
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     isShadowEnabled == null
>         ? isShadowEnabled = false
>         : isShadowEnabled = isShadowEnabled;
>     final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
>     return Container(
>       // alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
>       // width: deviceSize.width * 0.5 + passedText.length * 3,
>       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5),
>       height: deviceSize.height * 0.04,
>       decoration: BoxDecoration(
>         color: passedBGColor == null ? Colors.brown : passedBGColor,
>         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
>           Radius.circular(
>             deviceSize.height * 0.02,
>           ),
>         ),
>         border: Border.all(
>           color: passedBorderColor == null
>               ? Colors.transparent
>               : passedBorderColor,
>         ),
>         boxShadow: [
>           isShadowEnabled
>               ? BoxShadow(
>                   color: Colors.brown,
>                   blurRadius: 10.0, // has the effect of softening the shadow
>                   spreadRadius: 1.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
>                   offset: Offset(
>                     0.0, // horizontal
>                     1.0, // vertical
>                   ),
>                 )
>               : BoxShadow()
>         ],
>       ),
>       child: Row(
>         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
>         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>         children: [
>           passedIcon != null
>               ? Icon(
>                   passedIcon,
>                   color: Colors.white,
>                   size: deviceSize.height * 0.02,
>                 )
>               : Container(),
>           passedIcon != null
>               ? SizedBox(width: deviceSize.width * 0.01)
>               : SizedBox(),
>           Text(
>             passedText,
>             style: TextStyle(
>               fontSize: deviceSize.height * 0.018,
>               fontFamily: "Montserrat",
>               color: passedFontColor != null ? passedFontColor : Colors.white,
>             ),
>           ),
>         ],
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a stack? If you replace the stack with a column your dialog will not be pushed to the top of the screen.

Comment: No I need to show dialog widget over diff widgets. I need stack. Not column'